# geom_area plot with areas and outlines ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a stacked geom_area plot, but would like to outline each area plot (works on first 'red' area but not the blue) with a line. Here is my best attempt but I can't figure out how to make the line type stacked also.  Ideas?

[image: example]

```
df= data.frame(Time=as.numeric(strsplit('1939 1949 1959 1969 1979 1989 1999 2009 2019 2029 2039 2049 1939 1949 1959 1969 1979 1989 1999 2009 2019 2029 2039 2049', split=' ')[[1]] ),
               Acres=as.numeric(strsplit('139504.2 233529.0 392105.3 502983.9 685159.9 835594.7 882945.1 1212671.4 1475211.9 1717971.7 1862505.7 1934308.0 308261.4 502460.8 834303.1 1115150.7 1430797.8 1712085.8 1973366.1 1694907.7 1480506.0 1280047.6 1164200.5 1118045.3', split=' ')[[1]] ),
               WUClass= strsplit('DenseUrban DenseUrban DenseUrban DenseUrban DenseUrban DenseUrban DenseUrban DenseUrban DenseUrban DenseUrban DenseUrban DenseUrban Urban Urban Urban Urban Urban Urban Urban Urban Urban Urban Urban Urban', split=' ')[[1]]   
               )

a=ggplot(df,aes(x = Time,y = Acres,fill=WUClass))+ geom_area( position = 'stack'  )
plot(a)
a+ geom_line(aes(position = 'stack'))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add an outline to the area, simply change the `colour`:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Time,y = Acres,fill=WUClass)) +
  geom_area( position = 'stack') +
  geom_area( position = 'stack', colour="black", show_guide=FALSE)
```

But to draw the lines, do this:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Time, y = Acres, fill=WUClass, group=WUClass)) +
  geom_area() + geom_line(aes(ymax=Acres), position="stack")
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I've made the line width really large just to illustrate the difference.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Time, y = Acres, fill = WUClass)) + 
geom_area( position = 'stack', linetype = 1, size =2 ,colour="black" , 
show_guide=FALSE) +
geom_line(aes(position = 'stack'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Maiasaura! although i like the other guys answer a bit more since I don't have to worry about the lines in the legend

Answer (score 5):

The error was just that you were putting position="stack" inside aes(). Change to

```
a=ggplot(df,aes(x = Time,y = Acres, fill=WUClass))+
                   geom_area( position = 'stack'  )
a +geom_line( position = 'stack'  )
```

... and all is fine.