# Constructing an area plot with outlines for discrete variable (i.e. with steps)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Similar to [geom_area plot with areas and outlines ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323060/geom-area-plot-with-areas-and-outlines-ggplot), I'm trying to construct a stacked area plot with outlines. Since my variables are discrete I'm using geom_bar() for stacking them. The code is as follows:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)
x = 0:4
y1 = c(3,2,2,1,0)
y2 = c(1,1,0,0,0)
data = data.frame(x,y1,y2)
data.plot <-melt(data, id.vars = "x")
cols = c(y1="darkgrey",y2="lightgrey") 
p = ggplot(data.plot,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))
p +  geom_bar(aes(width=1),stat = "identity") + theme_bw() +  scale_fill_manual(values=cols)
```

Which gives [image: Stacked barplot]

My problem is now adding the outlines as in the example I referred to. I can use `colour="black"` in `geom_bar()` but this adds vertical lines between the bars which look quite ugly.

Does anyone have a suggestion to get these outlines? The solution doesn't have to be based on `geom_bar`.

If possible, I am also interested in a solution where only the dark grey part has an outline, since this outline has an important interpretation. Perhaps this could be based on some shifted version of `geom_line()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plotting code (I don't want to use `c` since that's a function):

```
p <- ggplot(data.plot, aes(x = x, y = value, fill = variable))
p <- p + geom_bar(aes(width = 1), stat = "identity") + theme_bw() +  scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
```

Now add a stepping line along the bars:

```
p <- p + geom_step(aes(x = x - 0.5), position = "stack")
```

It's a bit more work to fix a line along the axes:

```
library (dplyr)
y.max <- data.plot %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(s = sum(value))
y.max <- max(y.max$s)    
p + geom_step(aes(x = x - 0.5, ymax = value), position = "stack") + 
      annotate('segment',
               x = min(data.plot$x) - 0.5,
               xend = min(data.plot$x) - 0.5,
               y = 0,
               yend = y.max) +
      annotate('segment',
               x = min(data.plot$x) - 0.5,
               xend = max(data.plot$x) - 0.5,
               y = 0,
               yend = 0)
```

[image: plot]

I'd be interested in simpler solutions!

Comment: This gives me plenty of ideas to work with also for future graphs. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach, using `annotate("path")`.  This suggestion has hard-coded values for some of the path components, but I suspect there is a way to algorithmically fill in those values (perhaps with `gg_build()`.

```
p <- ggplot(data.plot,aes(x=x, y=value, fill=variable))
p <- p + geom_bar(aes(width=1), stat = "identity") + theme_bw() +  scale_fill_manual(values=cols)
p <- p + annotate(x=c(-.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5),
                  y=c(3, 3,   2,   2,   1,   1,   0  ), group = 1,  "path", color = "black", size = 2)
p <- p + annotate(x=c(min(x)-.5, min(x)+0.5, min(x)+0.5, min(x)+2.5, min(x)+2.5, min(x)+3.5, min(x)+3.5),
                  y=c(max(value), max(value), max(value)- 1,  max(value)- 1,  max(value)- 2,  max(value)- 2,  min(value)), group = 1,  "path", color = "black", size = 2)
p
```

[image]

Comment: @lawyerR This is probably the graph that I will put in the article. The manual coding is no problem since I only need 2 of these graphs. Since Axeman was first, and his answer is very similar, I'll accept his answer if you don't mind.